# SQL Server : cross apply makes columns to be nullable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm making a view but I'm a bit confused on why my fields are getting converted to nullable. I'm using SQL Server 2016.

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vwEmployeePTORequest]
AS
    SELECT 
        Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.DivisionID,
        PTORequests.PTORequestId, PTORequests.IsPaidOut,
        PTORequests.PayoutPayEntryEarningId,
        --Why do I have to use ISNULL here?
        ISNULL(SummaryDetails.TotalHours, 0) AS TotalHours,
        SummaryDetails.RequestStartDate, SummaryDetails.RequestEndDate,
        SummaryDetails.DivisionPTOAccrualId
    FROM 
        dbo.Employees
    INNER JOIN  
        dbo.GlobalIds ON Employees.GlobalId = GlobalIds.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Activities ON Activities.OriginatorGlobalId = GlobalIds.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.PTORequests ON Activities.ActivityId = PTORequests.ActivityId
    CROSS APPLY 
        dbo.GetEmployeePTORequestDetailSummary(PTORequests.PTORequestId) AS SummaryDetails;
```

And this is the function being called in `CROSS APPLY`:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeePTORequestDetailSummary]
    (@PTORequestId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
        (SELECT TOP 1 
             SUM(Hours) AS TotalHours,
             MIN(RequestDate) AS RequestStartDate,
             MAX(RequestDate) AS RequestEndDate,
             DivisionPTOAccrualId AS DivisionPTOAccrualId
         FROM 
             dbo.PTORequestDetails  
         WHERE 
             PTORequestId = @PTORequestId
         GROUP BY 
             PTORequestId, DivisionPTOAccrualId);
```

And this is the relevant portion of the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PTORequestDetails]
(
    [PTORequestDetailId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](19, 2) NOT NULL,
)
```

I'm a bit confused on why this is happening. As you can see my columns are not NULLABLE, the aggregate function return non-nullable types, and I'm using `CROSS APPLY` which works per-row similar to inner join.  Since it's a one to one it shouldn't create a nullable.

Can anyone explain why my columns are coming in as nullable, and how can I fix this in the function so that all other procedures using it do not have to specify the `ISNULL()` conditional for each selected column?

Comment: It’s not the cross apply. It is the aggregate functions. SUM, MIN, MAX are all assumed to be nullable because if you use them on an empty table with no GROUP BY they will return NULL.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for your response, that’s weird because when I use intellisense on them it says it returns an int

Comment: It returns an int. But nullable. You can see that is the case from http://rextester.com/EUGVE39896

Comment: If you have multiple DivisionPTOAcrrualId for the passed PTORequestId it is not deterministic what one will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the help, If you post this as an answers I will accept it.

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah that’s fine I had a comment in there about it before but for now the nondeterministic functionality is okay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not the cross apply. It is the aggregate functions. SUM, MIN, MAX are all assumed to be nullable because if you use them on an empty table with no GROUP BY they will return NULL.

Moreover SUM can return NULL instead of error on integer overflow if you use some deprecated session options.

So you would need to wrap the aggregates in an `ISNULL` to have the columns treated as not nullable.